# Boot errors with Ubuntu Budgie

Tags: boot, 17.04, budgie

I have no earthly idea what's going on so if you need any more information than what you can see in the video, I will gladly edit it into the question.

[This](https://youtu.be/EYX7A3y76No) is the link to the video. It's in Drive right now but if it asks you to download it to view it, comment and I'll find another place to upload it to view it.

The root directory is encrypted and it's set to log me in automatically.

Comment: did you encrypt the root directory?

Comment: Sorry but copy the contents from the boot.log into the question. I an not going to download a random video....

Comment: @ravery I updated the question with info at the bottom. @Rinzwind I can't find the file `boot.log` when I search the file system. I don't know how to find it any other way. I uploaded the video to YouTube and updated the link so you'll be able to see it without downloading.